# unix timestamp round to midnight

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

If I have a random unix timestamp, how can I round it down to today's midnight or the midnight selected by the user. The reason for this is that I want to add hours and minutes after a certain day's midnight.

For example if the timestamp is `1324189035` then how can I remove the hours, minutes, and seconds to put the timestamp at midnight for that day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('today', 1324189035));
```

Comment: this is beautiful.  I had see one where someone thinking outside of the box put like `$roundedStamp = $time - ($time % 86400);` and it was clever but not perfect.  It rounds up or down depending so it doesn't work.  This does :)

Comment: This will return a date string, you need to add `strtotime` in order to get timestamp of midnight that should wrap around the entire code that is being echo'ed.

Comment: @SolomonClosson `strtotime('today', 1324189035)` already there and does the thing, `date` is just to demonstrate it is actually the midnight.

Comment: awww, gotcha, got a bit confused there with the `date` echo.

Comment: In the desperate hope that this might help someone in my situation, a slight adapatation of this to get **number** of days from UNIX epoch (from the same timestamp to eliminate rounding errors): `round(strtotime('today', time()) / 86400))`. My use case was finding odd numbered days since Epoch to alternate a cron procedure `round($daysFromUnixEpoch) % 2 === 0`

Answer (score 18):

Because of how you're using it, I wouldn't calculate midnight at all: it is far easier to simply convert what you're adding to the timestamp into 24 hour time and then use strtotime:

```
echo strtotime("0:00",1324189035); // 1324184400
echo strtotime("17:50",1324189035); // 1324248600
```

And if you want to have that in human readable, use `date` and `m/d/Y H:i:s`:

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime('17:50',1324189035)); // 12/18/2011 17:50:00
```

Comment: This solution is most elegant and pleasing. It needs to be remembered that this is all GMT, so to get 17:50 in any other timezone, the time offset would need to be added before this time mapping, then taken off again afterwards (assuming you are ultimately looking for a GMT/UTC time for searching data in a database, for example).

Comment: It seems to map midnight to the *previous* midnight: `echo strtotime("0:00 +0000", 1443441600);` prints `1443398400`

Answer (score 8):

Simply Use

```
strtotime('today midnight');
```

Comment: This is very readable and very flexible too. e.g.: `strtotime('now + 1 year + 1 day midnight')`

Comment: Just wanted to add that strtotime('today midnight') and strtotime('midnight') both output the same timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime('today'));
```

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to use the **modulo** expression to remove the exceeded seconds from a round day timestamp.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$timestamp = time();

echo "timestamp : " . $timestamp . PHP_EOL;
echo "timestamp formatted : " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp) . PHP_EOL;

$diff = $timestamp % (60 * 60 * 24);

echo "diff : " . $diff . PHP_EOL;

$midnight = $timestamp - $diff;

echo "midnight : " . $midnight . PHP_EOL;
echo "midnight formatted : " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight) . PHP_EOL;
```

This would output the following result.

> timestamp : 1575451074
>
> timestamp formatted : 2019-12-04 09:17:54
>
> diff midnight : 1575417600
>
> midnight formatted : 2019-12-04 00:00:00

And here is a one liner function to get your midnight from any timestamp.

```
function getMidnight ($timestamp) { return $timestamp - ($timestamp % 86400); }
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d85c935e71fcf011284ae33658e0c68dd8d8c28

Answer (score 0):

How about just:
`date -d $(date +%F) +%s`