# Compute the unix timestamp for the previous midnight

Tags: java, datetime

How can you, in Java, compute the unix timestamp truncated to midnight?

[PHP examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550236/unix-timestamp-round-to-midnight) show making strings and then parsing them back.  There has to be a cleaner way to do it in Java than that, surely?

Comment: Midnight in which time zone? And can you use Joda Time?

Comment: @JonSkeet UTC and yes, I could use Joda Time although I'm not yet using it anywhere else

Comment: If you're doing any significant amount of date/time work, I'd *thoroughly* recommend using Joda Time :)

Comment: Note that for Java 8 you have a new date+time API which makes this much easier to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unix timestamp starts from midnight UTC so we can do the following

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long unixTimeStamp = c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 5):

For unix timestamps you can create function like this:

```
public long getMidnightTimestamp(long timestamp)
{
    return timestamp - timestamp % 86400; // 24 * 60 * 60 sec in one day 
}
```

And use it like this:

```
long currentTimestamp =  System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
long todayMidnightTimestamp = getMidnightTimestamp(currentTimestamp);
```

Comment: Leap seconds? This will be slightly imprecise i think. There have been 27 of them since 1970. (OK, forget it. unix time does no do leap seconds. That makes unix time slightly imprecise, but your trick will work 100%)

Comment: Smart! A neat workarround without the need to rely on Calendar/Date/SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

long midnightUnixTimestamp = c.getTime().getTime()/1000;
```